# Smartly deal with Option[T] in Scala

Tags: scala, option-type

I am developing some code using Scala and I am trying to smartly resolve a basic transformation between collections that contains some `Option[T]`.

Let's say that we have the following list

```
val list: List[(A, Option[B])] = // Initialization stuff
```

and we want to apply a transformation to `list` to obtain the following list

```
val transformed: List[(B, A)]
```

for all `Option[B]`s that evaluate to `Some[B]`. The best way I found to do this is to apply the following chain of transformations:

```
val transformed = 
  list.filter(_.isDefined)
      .map { case (a, Some(b)) => (b, a) }
```

However I feel that I am missing something. Which is the best way to deal with `Option[T]`s?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `collect`:

```
val transformed = list.collect {
  case (a, Some(b)) => (b, a)
}
```

Collect, as defined in the docs:

> Builds a new collection by applying a partial function to all elements of this list on which the function is defined.

Meaning, it yields a result only for elements which match any of the cases defined in your partial function. I like to think of it as a combined `filter` and `map`.