# Smartly deal with Option[T] in Spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, option-type

I am developing some code using the Scala API of Apache Spark and I am trying to smartly resolve a basic transformation between `RDD`s that contains some `Option[T]`.

Let's say that we have the following list

```
val rdd: RDD[(A, Option[B])] = // Initialization stuff
```

and we want to apply a transformation to `rdd` to obtain the following

```
val transformed: RDD[(B, A)]
```

for all `Option[B]`s that evaluate to `Some[B]`. The best way I found to do this is to apply the following chain of transformations:

```
val transformed = 
  rdd.filter(_.isDefined)
     .map { case (a, Some(b)) => (b, a) }
```

I know that if I was using a simple Scala `List` I could use the `collect` method:

```
val transformed = list.collect {
  case (a, Some(b)) => (b, a)
}
```

as stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302647/smartly-deal-with-optiont-in-scala) SO question of mine.

Using Spark `RDD`s instead, which kind of option do I have??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `flatMap`:

```
rdd.flatMap {
   case (a, Some(b)) => Some(b, a)
   case _ => None
}
```

Comment: @riccardo.cardin This is actually a valid solution :)

Comment: @riccardo.cardin I think I am answering the question. Let me know how this is not helping you and I will update my answer :)

Comment: @riccardo.cardin this is the answer to your question. Note that the collect function is equivalent to this usage of flatMap.

Answer (score 4):

`RDD` provides [`collect`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@collect[U](f:PartialFunction[T,U])(implicitevidence$29:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[U]) **transformation** which is equivalent to [`Iterable.collect`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterable.html#collect[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):Iterable[B]):

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq((1L, None), (2L, Some("a"))))
val transformed: RDD[(String, Long)] = rdd.collect {
  case (a, Some(b)) => (b, a)
}

transformed.count
// Long = 1 

transformed.first
// (String, Long) = (a,2)
```

Comment: you're right, I'm sorry. I didn't notice in the API that there are two versions of the `collect` method.

Comment: @azuras You are wrong. Please read documentation and source to understand how `collect: PartialFunction[T, U] => ClassTag[U] => RDD[U]` works.